# How to create AngularJS Filter Using Lodash to Achieve global search with multiple keyword?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash, angularjs-filter

I would like to create AngularJS Filter Using Lodash to Achieve global search with multiple keyword. I already tried ***.contains()***,   **.contains()**, **_.filter()** but really can't get it working.

ANGULARJS FILTER

```
.filter('multiKeywordSearch', function() {
    return function(obj, keywords) {
        if((typeof keywords === 'undefined') || keywords == "") {
            return obj; 
        }
        else{
            var keywords = keywords.split(" ");

            return _.filter(obj, function(keywords){
                    return //I REALLY DON'T KNOW WHAT TO USE      
            });
        }
    }
})
```

VIEW

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search">

<tr ng-repeat="generalDocument in generalDocuments | orderBy: 'id' | multiKeywordSearch: search">
            <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.company.company_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.branch.branch_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.document_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.description }}</td>
```

Comment: What are the search criteria?

Comment: I want to search anywhere. all values in the object. Most of the solutions I'm getting online are specifying some keys which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: If you found a solution which requires specifying keys you could adapt it by first getting all keys in the object and then using one of those solutions.

Comment: This kind of search may be expensive.  When pulling this data in the service I would just junk all the object values that you want to search from into a `.keywords` property, that you can search on.

Comment: @CorySilva I have only few records to manage and I don't think it will make the searching slow. 200 records is even hard to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
app.filter('multiKeywordSearch', function () {
    return function (collection, keywords) {
        if (!keywords) {
            return collection;
        } else {
            keywords = keywords.toUpperCase().split(" ");
            _.each(keywords, function (keyWord) {
                collection = _.filter(collection, function (item) {
                    for (var key in item) {
                        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(key.indexOf('$$hashKey') > -1)) {
                            if (typeof item[key] === 'string' && item[key].toUpperCase().indexOf(keyWord) > -1) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            });

            return collection;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a working [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MtKMSviV3i53zekcsHDk?p=preview)

Comment: hi @Reza, your plunker demo works great and very simple. But when I tried to apply the filter to my data, search doesn't work properly as it should. Is there anything I have to consider when applying the filter?

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work on fields with values as objects.

Comment: Example:[{id:1, company : { id: 1, name: "ABC Company"}, branch: {id:1, name: "Branch 1"}, status: "active"}]

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = [];
var keywords = ["John", "Doe"];
_.filter(data, function(obj) {
  var status = true;
  for(var i in keywords) {
    if(!status) return;
    status = _.contains(obj, keywords[i]);
  }
  if(status) results.push(obj);
});
```

That should do it.

If you want this search to be recursive I recommend using the `deepFilter` extension I created here: https://github.com/AndrewHenderson/underscore.deep

Comment: Hi @AndrewHenderson, I tried your solution but it doesn't work as well. I will try the extension you've made.